# A function that returns the numeric vector of some mathematical expressions

Tags: r

So I want to create a function that calculates some mathematical expressions and return a vector with the answers, let's call it `my_numeric_vector()`.
Let's say we have the expressions e^(pi/3) and cos(pi/6). I have tried to create a function but as I am fairly new to R I haven't completely got the grip of it. I tried:

```
my_numeric_vector()
   x <- c(exp(pi/3),cos(pi/6))
return my_numeric_vector(x)
```

However this does not work and I am sure that I should have more code. What I want it to do is to return the answers in vector form, as

```
[1] 2.84965390823 0.86602540378
```

or when I run the function

```
my_numeric_vector()
```

it should give the calculations directly. So where am I going wrong? I want it to be a simple but a functioning function.

Comment: In R a function is created using the function keyword. i.e. my_function_name <- function(arguments) {function_body}. I'd suggest reading up on R syntax

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to just create a variable so that the expression does not need to be evaluated every time we call the function:

```r
# A function without any input argument thus returning always the same result
my_numeric_vector <- function() {
  c(exp(pi/3),cos(pi/6))
}

my_numeric_vector()
#> [1] 2.8496539 0.8660254

# a vector in which the value is only calculated once
my_numeric_vector2 <- c(exp(pi/3),cos(pi/6))
my_numeric_vector2
#> [1] 2.8496539 0.8660254
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched everywhere but I could not find to do it like this (or at least I didn't understand it). This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll play around a bit with it, I think I just needed this as a start and I can go on by myself now!

Comment: A function with no arguments?  Why not create a vector instead evaluating the expression as required?  Maybe this is another matter that I need to study: When is a function with no arguments used in R?  Many thanks! One learns new things every day...

Comment: I created a function because this was being asked. Indeed, creating the vector once is the cleanest and fastest way, because we only need to calculate the result once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question:  Why do you need a function for this task?  I simply ran:

```
X <- c(exp(pi/3), cos(pi/6)); X
```

And I obtained:

```
> X <- c(exp(pi/3), cos(pi/6)); X
[1] 2.8496539 0.8660254
```

Which is what you want. Can you clarify please?

Comment: I know I don't need a function, but I wanted to create one, both for learning and for future problems I might get :)

Comment: Ah! Swell! Chapter 10 of [Venables](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) is a good place to start learning about functions in R.  I have written some functions to play around with R and one of my favorites is the factorial function that explains the recursion concept... I will look around for it or program it again for you... Take care...

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll check it out for sure!

Comment: ```factorialfn <- function(x){
  ifelse(x==1 || x==0, fact <- 1, fact <- x*factorialfn(x-1))
  fact
}

factorialfn(4)```  Is just the factorial function I promised you... It still needs work to verify that the argument is not negative and an integer (this one is done by checking if `x==round(x)`)